# Two looped async calls followed by a sync call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, promise, fetch

I need to edit previously saved messages that contain attachments. In the edit functionality, the user should be able to edit message title or text, replace existing attachments or delete attachments.

Scenario: User made changes to message text, replaced one attachment and deleted 2 attachments and hit Save. OnClick of Save button, the following actions need to happen

1. Replace and Delete API calls async first
2. If replace and delete is successful then api call to save changes to text

This is where I'm at..

`.then` of `Promise.all` in `replace` and `delete` is executed before the loop promise finishes, resulting in the outer promise (in `handleSave`) getting a resolved promise always.

`deleteData` and `replaceData` are arrays containing the data to be replaced/deleted

```
const delete = () => {
    if (deleteData.length > 0) {
      return Promise.all([
        deleteData.map(data => fetch(url)
          .then((response) => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error('Delete Failed');
            }
          })
        ),
      ]).then(() => Promise.resolve('Deleted'));
    }
    return Promise.resolve('Nothing to delete');
  };

const replace = () => {
    if (replaceData.length > 0) {
      return Promise.all([
        replaceData.map(data => fetch(url)
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 400) {
              response.text().then((error) => {
                const errorObject = JSON.parse(error);
                throw new Error(error);
              });
            } else if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error('Update Failed');
            }
          })
        ),
      ]).then(() => Promise.resolve('Replaced'));
    }
    return Promise.resolve('Nothing to replace');
  };

const saveMessage = () => {
    fetch(saveUrl)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.status === 400) {
              response.text().then((error) => {
                const errorObject = JSON.parse(error);
                throw new Error(error);
              });
            } else if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error('Save Failed');
            }
        });
}

const handleSave = () => {
  Promise.all([replace, delete])
     .then(() => {
       saveMessage();
      }).catch((e) => {
        //Catch action
      })
  }
```

Comment: Your `save` doesn't return anything, you probably want to `return` the fetch call so it can be caught below in handleSave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To your `Promise.all`s, you're currently passing an array containing a single item, where that item is an array of Promises. As a result, the `Promise.all` resolves immediately.

Pass an array of Promises to `Promise.all` instead - that is, just the `.map`, not `[data.map(...)]`. Change:

```
return Promise.all([
  deleteData.map(data => fetch(url)
```

to

```
return Promise.all(
  deleteData.map(data => fetch(url)
```

and

```
return Promise.all([
  replaceData.map(data => fetch(url)
```

to

```
return Promise.all(
  replaceData.map(data => fetch(url)
```

Also, inside `replace`, it isn't returning the *inner* `.text` Promise when there's a 400 error, so its mapped `Promise.all` won't reject when you want it to. Change:

```
if (response.status === 400) {
  response.text().then((error) => {
    const errorObject = JSON.parse(error);
    throw new Error(error);
  });
```

to

```
if (response.status === 400) {
  return response.json().then((error) => {
    throw new Error(error);
  });
```

(note that you can use `.json()` instead of `JSON.parse`)

Also, for your `saveMessage` errors to be handled in the `catch`, you should return each of its Promises too:

```
const saveMessage = () => {
  return fetch(saveUrl)
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 400) {
        return response.json().then((error) => {
          throw new Error(error);
        });
      } else if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Save Failed');
      }
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks but that isnt the problem.. The problem is that the loops in replace and delete are not working as expected. I prefer to keep .text() because if response is empty .json() fails

Comment: It's definitely at least one part of the problem. Can you show where you define `deleteData`, `replaceData`, `replace`, `delete`?

Comment: deleteData and replaceData are arrays containing the data to be replaced/deleted

Comment: I see the issue, you're passing an array of arrays to `Promise.all` instead of an array of Promises.

Comment: Are you sure you added the `return`? That is, `return response.text()` or `.json()` instead of just `response.text()` or `.json()`?

Comment: That was it mate! Thanks!